# gatling load testing Restful Api with @RequestParam

Tags: rest, gatling

I am writing a Gatling load test for Restful api test.  The endpoint accepts @RequestParam, however I am getting 400 when I call the rest endpoint from my scala script.  Here is how I have it setup.

```
Scala script for LoadTest with Gatling:
   val getMails = exec(http("GET_MAILS")
              .get("/api/v1/users/${userId}/mails")
              .formParam("dateFrom", "1430987200")
              .formParam("dateTo", "1432987200")
```

Rest Endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/{userId}/mails", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity getMailsB`enter code here`yFilter(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
                                            @RequestParam(value="dateFrom") Long dateFrom,            
                                            @RequestParam(value="dateTo") Long dateTo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should probably be using `queryParam` to pass "dateFrom" and "dateTo" in the query, not `formParam`.

Then, your @RequestMapping shows that it's only triggered if the "Accept" header is "application/json". There's nothing in the Gatling sample you provided proving that you're indeed properly setting this header to this value.

Comment: Then please validate :)